# How to get an Excel Blank Cell As NULL

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have to get value from excel using Apache POI. I have two cases

1. Have to get Exact value from Excel cell
2. The NULL value should be return while get the Value

For first case i have using `new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(row.getCell(index))` this method exactly return the value from Excel.  But if the cell has Empty value then it didn't return value as NULL.

I also tried with `new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(row.getCell(index, HSSFRow.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL))`

Please refer the attached screen shot!  [Here we have to get the Description value as null
Excel with null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkjlT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of [DatFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) is to give you back a non-null string that looks like what Excel would have displayed for the given cell. For an empty cell, be that null or blank, that's an empty string. That's explained in the [javadocs for the formatCellValue method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29):

> When passed a null or blank cell, this method will return an empty String ("")

If you want to have a null value for empty cells, you should do tweak your code to be:

```
// One per workbook is fine, save re-creating each time
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

// Per cell
Cell c = row.getCell(index, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
if (c == null) return null;
return formatter.formatCellValue(c);
```